# how do i install zope interface with python 2.6?

Tags: python, zope.interface

During setup, I'm like missing vcvarsall.bat

> running build
>   running build_py
>   running build_ext
>   building '_zope_interface_coptimizations' extension
>   error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`vcvarsall.bat` is a batch file that comes with MSVC. Make sure that it is in your `%PATH%`.

Comment: i've installed msvc and had C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC added to my path but still the error unable to find vcvarsall.bat persists...

Comment: oh i got it, i needa use visual studio 2008 instead of 2010. thanks Ignacio

Answer (score 0):

Your could use another install script. Use `mingw32`.

```
python setup.py build -c mingw32
```